# using awk to handle 2 text files

Tags: awk

I have a text file like this small example:

```
chr12   2904300 2904315 peak_8        167     .       8.41241 21.74573        16.71985        65
chr1    3663184 3663341 peak_9        77      .       7.86961 12.16321        7.70843 37
chr1    6284759 6285189 peak_10       220     .       13.85268        27.34231        22.06610        332
chr1    6653468 6653645 peak_11       196     .       13.59296        24.85586        19.68392        117
chr1    8934964 8935095 peak_12       130     .       8.82937 17.84867        13.03453        36
```

and have another file like the 2nd example:

```
ENSG00000004478|12|2904119|2904309
ENSG00000002933|7|150498624|150498638
ENSG00000173153|11|64073050|64073208
ENSG00000001626|7|117120017|117120148
ENSG00000003249|16|90085750|90085881
ENSG00000003056|12|9102084|9102551
```

the first example is `tab` separated and the 2nd example is `|`
separated.I want to select only the rows from the 1st example if "the
average of columns 2 and 3 in the first example is between the 3rd and
4th columns in the 2nd example and also the number of the first column
in the 1st example is equal to the 2nd column of the 2nd example".
for example the output from these 2 examples would be:

```
chr12   2904300 2904315 peak_8        167     .       8.41241 21.74573        16.71985        65
```

I am trying to do that using awk:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=($2+$3)/2;b[FNR]=$0;next} (FNR in a) && ($3<=a[FNR] && $4>=a[FNR]){print b[FNR]}'  file1  FS="|"  file2
```

but it does not work and returns nothing. do you know how I can correct the code?

Comment: Seems like it'd be simpler to merge both files beforehand?

Comment: no actually this is not simple merging.

Comment: I know it's not simple merging, but you want to do both files line-by-line, right?

Comment: @ARM, I believe I had written that your shown code. So why don't you post problems in your actual thread? This is a duplicate of it.

Answer (score 0):

## solution

```
 awk 'NR==FNR ? \!((a[NR]=$1)&&(z[NR]=$0)&&(avr[NR]=($3+$2)/2)) : (($4>=avr[FNR] && avr[FNR]>=$3)&&(a[FNR]=="chr"$2)){print z[FNR] }' file1 FS="|" file2
```

file1 `FS=" "` by default, file2 `FS="|"`

## awk `?:` part description

1). `NR==FNR` check if the file we are parsing is the first or second

**`NR`** - The total number of input records seen so far.

**`FNR`** - The input record number in the current input file

2) if working on first file `\!((a[NR]=$1)&&(z[NR]=$0)&&(avr[NR]=($3+$2)/2))`

**`\!`** - prevent printing to screen

**`a[NR]=$1`** - array holds the first field of file

**`z[NR]=$0`** - array holds the lines of first file

**`avr[NR]=($3+$2)/2`** - array holds the average requested from the first file

3)    check for conditions of second file to print lines:

**a)** `(($4>=avr[FNR] && avr[FNR]>=$3)&&(a[FNR]=="chr"$2)){print z[FNR] }`

**b)**`($4>=avr[FNR] && avr[FNR]>=$3)` - check average of first file is in between the values of fields 3 & 4 of the second file

**c)**`(a[FNR]=="chr"$2)` - check that numbers in field 1(first file) & field 2(second file) are the same

**d)**if conditions are true print to screen the line from the first file (`z[FNR]`)